# Android - how to stop continuous terminal action (ping) programmaticaly?

Tags: android

I am working on a simple app but don't know how to stop continuous action in terminal such as PING programmatically.

I just want to know the command, then I'll add it to runtime.getruntime.exec...

I know there's a CTRL+C shortcut in pc but how do I execute this on Android?

Sorry for not adding examples, I'm writing from my phone.

Comment: Volume down + c?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly send CTRL + C, but take a look at `Process.sendSignal()` ([Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#sendSignal%28int,%20int%29))

First, get the process ID of the ping-process.
Then you can easily send a `Process.sendSignal(yourPid, Process.SIGNAL_QUIT);`

Comment: Was hopeful this would be an answer for me, I need to send a proper "quit" signal to a ping command that was started with exec().   Unfortunately SIGNAL_QUIT does not stop the ping, SIGNAL_KILL does, however it is a hard kill, and results without the ping statistics being returned

Answer (score 1):

*Another way:*

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping 127.0.0.1");
proc.destroy();
```

As you execute your command, you get the relating process. You can use it to stop your ping, too.

Answer (score 0):

After debugging for a long time I found out how to solve the problem 
"**Kill results without the ping statistics being returned**".

1. Get pid of ping process.
   Ex:

   `Progress proc = runtime.exec("ping 192.168.1.1");`

   where `proc` will be something like ***Process[pid=2343]***, so you need to extract 2343.
2. Then when you are reading the ping output, you can use 
   **`"Runtime.getRuntime().exec("kill -INT " + 2243);"`** to kill the process.

---

```java
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream());  
BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(reader);  
String line;  

while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {   
    echo.append(line).append("\n");  
    if (UserStopPing) {              
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("kill -INT " + temp);   
}    
proc.waitFor();
```

This program will stop ping and you will get the statistic also [variable echo].

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.
There is a `CTRL` option on your screen. Press that and then enter `c`.
[image: 1]
This might help you.

Answer (score -1):

Just in case people are still looking for a solution to this -- On an Android the equivalent of CTRL+C is "Volume down button" + C on your keyboard. This should stop the ping.